# Using mysqli_result::fetch_object with my own class doesn't works

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, namespaces

I'll try to use fetch_object('Classname') to test this method.

**The Class Inserent in Inserent.php:**

```
namespace classes\model;

 class Inserent{
    private $nummer;
    private $nickname;
    private $email;

    public function __construct ($nummer, $nickname, $email){
        $this->nummer = $nummer;
        $this->nickname = $nickname;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getNummer(){
        return $this->nummer;
    }

    public function setNummer($nummer){
        $this->nummer = $nummer;
    }
 ...
 }
```

**The use is in a Mapper-Class InserentDAO.php:**

```
namespace classes\mapper;
use classes\model\Inserent;

class InserentDAO{
    private $dbConnect;

    public function __construct (){
        $this->dbConnect = MySQLDatabase::getInstance();
    }

    public function readAll(){
        $sql = "SELECT inserentennummer, nickname, email FROM inserent";
        $inserent = null;
        $inserentList = array();

        if ($result = $this->dbConnect->query($sql)) {

            while ($inserent = $result->fetch_object('classes\model\Inserent')) {
                $inserentList[] = $inserent;
            }
            $result->close();
        }
        return $inserentList;
    }
...
}
```

I get errors and my Objects are empty:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for classes\model\Inserent::__construct()
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 10
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for classes\model\Inserent::__construct()
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 10
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for classes\model\Inserent::__construct()
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: nummer in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: nickname in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\secondStep\classes\model\Inserent.php on
>   line 13

But if I change the code, in the Mapper, it will works.

**part of the code InserentDAO.php instead:**

```
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
     $inserent = new Inserent($obj->inserentennummer, $obj->nickname, $obj->email);
     $inserentList[] = $inserent;
}
```

Comment: Which line is what?

Comment: Did you check a manual? There're some comments and texts you need to read.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `fetch_object` invokes an empty constructor and then sets the properties according to result columns it fetched. [There is a comment on the manual confirming that.](https://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php#119298)

So this is what `fetch_object("classes\model\Inserent")` is doing:

```
$object = new classes\model\Inserent();
$object->inserentennummer = $result['inserentennumer'];
$object->nickname = $result['nickname'];
$object->email = $result['email'];
return $object;
```

This is why it's complaining about missing parameters and undefined variables (they're `private`).

The obvious solution is to refactor your class to provide an empty constructor and public properties:

```
namespace classes\model;

class Inserent{
    public $nummer;
    public $nickname;
    public $email;

    public function __construct ($nummer = 0, $nickname = "", $email = ""){
        //...
```

An alternative to making the properties public would be to use the [`__set`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic method, but you'd still have to provide a zero-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!!

I had to change the constructor in my Class Inserenten.php in the way that you explain. Also I had to change the property name from "$nummer" to "$inserentennummer", because the database table property has this name. Also I had to add querys to the constructor.

The method __set() was no help.

```
class Inserent{
    private $inserentennummer;
    private $nickname;
    private $email;


    public function __construct ($inserentennummer = 0, $nickname = "", $email = ""){
        if(!$this->inserentennummer){
            $this->inserentennummer  = $inserentennummer;
        }

        if(!$this->nickname){
            $this->nickname  = $nickname;
        }

        if(!$this->email){
            $this->email  = $email;
        }       
    }
```

And then it's working :-)